# Наложить картинку на другую по не целочисленной координате

Tags: python

Сейчас наложение одной картинки на другую происходит с помощью `PIL`, `Image.paste`:

```
from PIL import Image


img0 = Image.open("foo.jpg")
img1 = Image.open("bar.jpg")

img0.paste(img1, (x, y))
```

Но `Image.paste` не позволяет задавать не целочисленные координаты.
Каким образом наложить одну картинку на другую по не целочисленным координатам (с антиалиасингом).

(округление/преобразование позиции наложения к `int` не дает приемлемых результатов)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока решил таким костылем:

- обе картинки увеличиваются в 10 раз
- координаты для наложения умножаются в 10 раз и округляются до целого
- одна картинка накладываются на другую по полученным целочисленным координатам
- итоговая картинка уменьшается в 10 раз (с антиалисингом)

Таким образом будет учитываться дробная часть координат до десятых, что на глаз уже вполне приемлемо. Из минусов - дополнительные манипуляции, требующие времени и расхода памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Пробовали ли вы использовать
[composite](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.composite)

```
Image.composite(image1, image2, mask) ⇒ image
```

> Creates a new image by interpolating between the given images, using
> the corresponding pixels from a mask image as alpha. The mask can have
> mode “1”, “L”, or “RGBA”. All images must be the same size.

Comment: К сожалению `composite` позволяет объединять только одинакового размера картинки.